# Stuck on X mode (INSERT COMPL), how do I quit?

Tags: ins-completion

I've been using vim for 3 years and this is the first time I hear about this mode. This is also quite embarrassing.

I have no idea what did I type, I didn't intend to enter this mode. Vim will write to the buffer every single keystroke or mouse input that I do: if I click, I see a `^[[<0;84;22m^[[<0;84;22M` on the screen. If I type ANYTHING, it's be written to the buffer.

I tried doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, etc..  Literally <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ every single key in the keyboard, and also every single key without <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

I have unsaved changes, is there a way for me to save and restart neovim?

Comment: Try `<C-O>` to run a single normal mode command (such as `:wq<CR>`). If that doesn't work, maybe `<C-L>` which is the equivalent for `evim` (the "easy" mode...)

Comment: sounds like you are still in bracketed-paste mode. I believe this is a bug in neovim. I believe there is no easy work-around